# MAC - terminal wont configure GITHUB. | git config --global user.name "Your Name Here" | Cant get this and the email to work

Tags: git, macos

MAC - terminal will not configure GITHUB.

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name Here".
```

I cannot get this and the email to work. I have created an account on GitHub but it  won't allow me to sign in on the terminal.
Any suggestions?. I am trying to run rails on ruby.

Comment: Do you have git installed?

Comment: You seem to have mixed GitHub with git

Answer (score 0):

Without the exact error, it would be only guessing, but do remember that simply setting user.name / user.email has nothing to do with authentication: it only help for creating new commit with the right author name/email.

If you are using a GitHub https url, see "[Caching your GitHub password in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/)" and "[Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/)": that will help cache your credentials (GitHub username/password)